# linq sql join gets null with query syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core-3.1

in my asp.net core mvc 3 project, when I use method syntax, the department name appears in the table on index view, but when I use the query syntax, the department name does not appear. On debugging course.Department comes null. I can't figure out what is my fault?

**Course and Department model**

```
public class Course
    {
        [Key]
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }

public class Department
    {       
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public decimal Budget { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

**CourseController**

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //method syntax
            //var courses = _context.Courses.Include(x=>x.Department).ToList();

            //query syntax
            var courses = from course in _context.Courses
                          join dept in _context.Departments on course.DepartmentId equals dept.DepartmentId
                          select course;


            return View(courses);
        }
```

**index.cshtml**

```
.....
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CourseName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Credits)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department.DepartmentName)
            </td>
       </tr>
....
```

Comment: Your fault is the missing `.Include()` statement within the query syntax. And due to the fact that it isn't available as query syntax you have to mix both writing. And I don't like the mix up, why I always use the method syntax.

Comment: Why do you expect it to appear in the second case? It's the EF Core specific `Include` method which populates it, not the method or query syntax.

Comment: Also why you ever need that manual joining? `Department` navigation property represents exactly that join, so it is really redundant.